# How to know generated field of child entity? Does ORM preserve child element order?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, one-to-many

I have a `User` entity and an `Action` entity. Each user can have many actions, so this is one-to-many relationship. I have defined it's fetch type as `FetchType.EAGER`, so in order to add a child record, I need to add it to parent entity and save it.

Now what about generated id of child record, how to know it? Can I be sure, that new child instance is at the end of children list?

```
public long addNewAction(User user, String descr) {

   Action action = new Action();
   action.setLocatDate( LocalDate.now() );
   action.setLocalTime( LocalTime.now() );
   action.setUser( user );
   action.setDescription( descr );

   user.getActions().add( action );
   userRepository.save(user);

   long addedId = user.getActions().get( user.getActions().size()-1 ).getId();

   return addedId;
}
```

entites are described as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
   private List<Action> actions;

   @Column(name = "SCREEN_NAME", nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String screenName;

}


@Entity
@Table(
   name = "ACTION",
   uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"USER_ID", "LOCAL_DATE", "LOCAL_TIME"}))
@JsonDeserialize(using = MealDeserializer.class)
public class Action {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
   private User user;

   @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
   @Column(name = "LOCAL_DATE")
   private LocalDate localDate;

   @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
   @Column(name = "LOCAL_TIME")
   private LocalTime localTime;

   @Column(name = "DESCR")
   private String description;

}
```

How to accomplish?

Comment: so this action object that you created is replaced by some other action object after user is saved?

Comment: Yes, but I need it should be that very object, was just added by ORM.

Answer (score 1):

When persisting an object graph, the entity manager does not reorder the list elements - the entities are modified in place and have their IDs set by the entity manager. That's why `em.persist(entity)` returns `void` - it operates on the given entity and does not return a new one (as opposed to `em.merge()`). So whatever order you have in the list, it will be preserved after calling `save()`.

This does not hold to subsequent fetches from the DB (using different entity manager instances / different transactions) - the order of the entities on the list depends on the DB order and that is undetermined. You can use an [`@OrderColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation (requires an extra column in the DB) to keep the elements of the list in a consistent order.

Comment: same question as I asked OP: does that mean that you can just call getID() method on that Action object (assuming it was updated by entity manager in place) ?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: yes, as I wrote "the entities are modified in place" - they are not substituted, but just have their auto-generated properties (in this case: the ID) filled in. That applies to the whole entity graph, not just the root of it that is passed to `persist` (here: `user` instance). So even the `Action` objects will stay the same instances, will just have their IDs set.

Comment: I don't understand then why OP had time to write a question here but did not simply check that Action gets ID after persist :)